# What is the proper way to check if a file/folder in a Box account is read-only using the Box Android library (apiV2)?

Tags: java, android, box-api

I am working on an android app used to access a Box account. The problem I am facing is how to determine a folder/file in the user's account is read only (shared with him/her as a Viewer) so that the upload/delete operations can be disabled.

What I currently do is:

1) Get the items in a folder:

`BoxCollection itemsCollection = _boxClient.getFoldersManager()
                .getFolderItems(folderId, folderContentRequest);`

```
    String userMail = ...
    ArrayList<BoxTypedObject> result = null;
```

2) Determine which one is folder, get it's collaborations, check if it's accessible by the logged-in user, and check whether he is an editor:

```
    if (itemsCollection != null) {
        result = itemsCollection.getEntries();
        for(BoxTypedObject boxObject : result) {
            if(boxObject instanceof BoxAndroidFolder) {
                BoxAndroidFolder folder = (BoxAndroidFolder)boxObject;
                List<BoxCollaboration> folderCollaborations = _boxClient.getFoldersManager().getFolderCollaborations(folder.getId(), null);
                for(BoxCollaboration collaboration : folderCollaborations) {
                    if( userMail.equalsIgnoreCase(collaboration.getAccessibleBy().getLogin()) &&
                            !BoxCollaborationRole.EDITOR.equalsIgnoreCase(collaboration.getRole()))
                        System.out.println("" + folder.getName() + " is readonly");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, is there a simpler and faster (fewer requests) way to get that property of a folder with the android SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check the owner of the folder (folder.getOwnedBy()), if it's the current user then you don't need to check collaborations. However if it's not the current user you'll have to check collaborations.